# XLWT - AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Workbook'

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

To install xlwt, I followed the instruction (using vitualenv) of the following website: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt

However, when I was running the example, I got the following error:

**AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Workbook'**

Could anyone give me a hint on what is going on? Thanks a lot..

Comment: Can you please post the stack trace also?

Comment: thank you, do you mean traceback? I try to do it now..

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bisheng\Downloads\0FRM_wall\0jobs\python\xls\xlwt.py", line 1, in <module>
    import xlwt
  File "C:\Users\bisheng\Downloads\0FRM_wall\0jobs\python\xls\xlwt.py", line 4, in <module>
    wb = xlwt.Workbook()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Workbook'
[Finished in 0.1s]